# Display Online PDF in Android Webview using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**Problem Statement:**

I am trying to display a hosted PDF from a secure site using `https` in a `WebView` using `Xamarin.Forms`. It is also worth noting that the PDF does load in a desktop browser.

**What I Have Tried:**

I have a custom renderer for the Android `WebView` control.

If I try using the [pdfjs](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf) library, I get the following output[image]

Below is my custom renderer:

```
public class BindableWebviewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    public BindableWebviewRenderer(Context context)
        :base (context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var customWebView = Element as BindableWebView;
            Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("file:///android_asset/Content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.URL))));
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried using

```
Control.LoadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + customWebView.URL);
```

But this just displays an empty page (it is also worth noting that the URL created from this also does not work in a browser).

**Questions I Have Already Consulted:**

- [Show a pdf into a webview from a link inside that Website Xamarin
  android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762140/show-a-pdf-into-a-webview-from-a-link-inside-that-website-xamarin-android)
- [Android WebView: Display Website with PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892477/android-webview-display-website-with-pdf)
- [xamarin/docs-archive](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf)

Comment: What is "customWebView.URL", a local (cached) file, remote, an asset or raw resource, etc?

Comment: @SushiHangover It is a URL pointing to a hosted PDF

Comment: "hosted": http or https? can that url be loaded into a browser (or curl downloaded) (i.e. it is not a google doc share url or dropbox , etc...)

Comment: @SushiHangover as I mention at the start of the question, it is hosted on HTTPS. And yes, it does load in a browser.

Comment: If you replace your url to another pdf url, will it work?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro, sorry, not sure what you mean

Comment: You are saying you cant load your pdf from your URL, what about trying to load another pdf?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro No PDF will load, from any URL that I have used. Even publicly available ones

Comment: Did you tried  `Control.SetWebViewClient(new FormsWebViewClient()); ` create a FormsWebViewClient(extend WebViewClient) to override `OnReceivedSslError` method, set  public override void OnReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
        {
          //  base.OnReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            handler.Proceed();
        }